When configuring cmake, I would like to add the header file into one folder
Since the stm32 vscode extension was updated to 2.0, we have been developing stm32 using vscode.
It wasn't difficult to add a library that you created yourself through CMakeListes.txt.
The function I want is to bundle the added library into one folder.
I searched it, but it wasn't the result of what I wanted.
I'd appreciate it if you could help me.
now:
#include <types.h>
#include <test.h>

i want:
#include <test/types.h>
#include <test/test.h>

directory structure
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── CMakePresets.json
├── Core
│   ├── Inc
│   │   ├── FreeRTOSConfig.h
│   │   ├── gpio.h
│   │   ├── main.h
│   │   └── usart.h
│   └── Src
│       ├── freertos.c
│       ├── gpio.c
│       ├── main.c
│       ├── syscalls.c
│       ├── sysmem.c
│       ├── system_stm32f4xx.c
│       └── usart.c
├── Middlewares
│   └── Test
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       ├── Inc
│       │   ├── types.h
│       │   └── test.h
│       └── Src
├── STM32F429ZITx_FLASH.ld
├── stm32_test.ioc
├── cmake
│   └── gcc-arm-none-eabi.cmake
└── startup_stm32f429xx.s


./CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

#
# This file is generated only once,
# and is not re-generated if converter is called multiple times.
#
# User is free to modify the file as much as necessary
#

# Setup compiler settings
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_C_EXTENSIONS ON)


# Define the build type
if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Debug")
endif()

# Set the project name
set(CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME stm32_test)

# Include toolchain file
include("cmake/gcc-arm-none-eabi.cmake")

# Enable compile command to ease indexing with e.g. clangd
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS TRUE)

# Enable CMake support for ASM and C languages
enable_language(C ASM)

# Core project settings
project(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})
message("Build type: " ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE})

# Create an executable object type
add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})

# Add STM32CubeMX generated sources
add_subdirectory(cmake/stm32cubemx)

# Add UltraSonic library
add_subdirectory(Middlewares/UltraSonic)

# Link directories setup
target_link_directories(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    # Add user defined library search paths
)

# Link options
target_link_options(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    -u _printf_float # to print float values
)

# Add sources to executable
target_sources(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    # Add user sources here
)

# Add include paths
target_include_directories(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    # Add user defined include paths
)

# Add project symbols (macros)
target_compile_definitions(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    # Add user defined symbols
)

# Add linked libraries
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
    stm32cubemx
    test
    # Add user defined libraries
)



./Middlewares/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

# Enable CMake support for ASM and C languages
enable_language(C ASM)

# Core project settings
project(
  test
  LANGUAGES   CXX   
  VERSION     1.0.0
)

add_library(test INTERFACE)

# Add include paths
target_include_directories(test INTERFACE
    Inc
    # Add user defined include paths
)

message(STATUS "test")


You didn't say what happens instead of the desired behavior.

@Ilya
I was able to do the same programming as ./Middlewares/CMakeLists.txt when I analyzed simple cmake examples and the cmakelist.txt file given as a base.
I want to make sure that I can put the header file in one folder as a type hint when building without changing the folder structure.
now: #include <test.h>
i want:#include <test/test.h>


i want:
#include <test/types.h>


If you want the file to be inside a test directory, create the directory and move it there. Change your file structure to:
├── Middlewares
│   └── Test
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       ├── Inc
             \- test
     │       │   ├── types.h
     │       │   └── test.h

Note, subjective: I find it highly confusing that your directories mix upper case and lower case letters. I would consider making directories lowercase only.

Thank you for your resp :)
I'm also a person who likes to use lower cases in the folder structure.
However, the stm32 template uses a strange structure :(

Is it impossible unless you change the folder structure?

impossible unless you change the folder structure? test/types.h is a path, so test is a directory. The directory has to exists somewhere.
